# Who is this commentator to many international badminton events?

Tags: trivia, badminton

Over the past few years, I've watched many badminton games on YouTube. At first, video-ed ASTRA broadcasts, but, nowadays, the BWF is hosting many of the international badminton events.

I would like to know the name of the female commentator who provided the commentary to many events. She appears in the final on the [Yonex Japan Open 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGIE6wWW95Q&list=SPA7ZcagI0frB-wHEhXsNzUiLI2OoEJTaH&index=4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gill Clark

Most likely, this is [Gillian Clark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillian_Clark_(badminton)) ("OSIM BWF World Superseries TV Commentator"). See a recent video with her [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=DpgCodzKNPE#t=102) (from 1:42).

[image]

Gill Clark can also be found on [the website for the Yonex Japan Open 2013](http://yonexopenjp.com/2013/en/topics_0826.html): "YONEX OPEN JAPAN – memories of a commentator by Gill Clark".